# if statement , && operators logic ( What is the importance of coding such trick ? )

Tags: c#, performance, if-statement, logical-operators

```
 public List<Product> SetProducts { get; set; }
 public string ParentSetId { get; set; }
```

First Case:

```
if (SetProducts.Any(p => p.blabla== Enum.blabla) && string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParentSetId))
```

Second Case:

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParentSetId) && SetProducts.Any(p => p.blabla== Enum.blabla))
```

&& operators works from left to right, so if statement will behave differently in each case.
We know if statement will be checked before left condition then if result "true" looking right statement.

And second case more useful.

What are the advantages out of them ?

What is the importance of coding such trick ?

thanks

Comment: Did you heard about lazy evaluation ?

Comment: What's the question actually?

Comment: this is the question ; 
What are the advantages out of them ?

What is the importance of coding such trick ?

Comment: Advantages compared to what? There really isn't a (clear) question here. And there is no 'trick' involved, just normal program logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`&&` will do a **short circuit evaluation**, so if the first condition is false, there is no need to check the second condition.

Considering that, your second code snippet appears better since comparison for `string.IsNullOrEmpty(ParentSetId)` *could* be cheaper as compared to  going through the list of items and checking using `Enumerable.Any`.

Answer (score 4):

This trick is important when i.e. one condition shouldn't be checked if another hasn't been satisfied.

For example:

```
if (node != null && node.data != key) {
    ...
}
```

If we swapped the two conditions, (i.e. `node.data != key` was checked first), then we risk dereferencing a null pointer. As written, however, we make sure `node` is *not* a null pointer before trying to dereference it.

Answer (score 2):

What you are referring to is known as short-circuit Boolean evaluation.

They are often used as guards, as in

`if (someObject != null && someOperationInvolvingSomeObject)`

thus preventing an exception in the case where `someObject` was null.

They can also sometimes be used to rearrange logic for better performance, e.g. from

`if (slowMethod() || fastMethod())`

to

`if (fastMethod() || slowMethod())`